# How does INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE work on a table partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How does INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE work on a SQL Server table partition?

Technical explaination please how the SQL server engine handles table partition vs non table partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL optimiser will use the query predicates to decide on how many table partitions will be affected. This makes the query run faster as unnecessary data is not read from disk. The query will then be run against the relevant data blocks in the affected partitions. To the user this is completely transparent.

Comment: What actually is modified on the primary table? (apart from indexes)

How does the SQL engine know where to insert the row, update, delete etc? there must be something to tell it "hey there partition table is located here"! ,

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx) by Kimberly Tripp to be incredibly useful in figuring out the ins and outs of table partitioning. It's about 40 pages long, technically detailed, and a printout sits on my desk as a permanenet reference.